# Pascal recursive summation function school practice problem

Tags: recursion, pascal, lazarus, freepascal

This function is a school practice problem (it is running but does not work properly).

My task is to call for a integer from the user.
When the number arrives, my task is to write out (with a recursive algorithm)
what is the sum of the number with the numbers before the given number.
For example if our number is 10 then the upshot is 55 because 1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+10 = 55, etc.

I've already tried to write this code:

```
function egesszamosszeg(n:integer) : integer;
begin
    egesszamosszeg:=0
    if n=1 then 
        egesszamosszeg:=1
    else
        for n:=1 to egesszamosszeg do
        begin
            egesszamosszeg:=egesszamosszeg+1;
        end; 
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject); 
var egesszam:integer; 
begin
    egesszam:=strtoint(Inputbox('','Give an integer please!',''));
    Showmessage(inttostr(Egesszamosszeg(egesszam))); 
end;
```

My problem is that I do not know what is the main problem with this code.

Comment: FWIW, you should perhaps learn how to properly indent and format your code. It is hard to read (also because of the unusual function and variable names).

Answer (score 0):

> I do not know what is the main problem with this code.

There are several problems with your code: it's iterative, not recursive; it's way too complicated; this loop:

```
for n:=1 to egesszamosszeg do
```

is effectively:

```
for n:=1 to 0 do
```

Consider this simple function which effectively implements the gist of your problem:

```
function egesszamosszeg(n:integer) : integer;
begin
    egesszamosszeg := n;

    if (n > 1) then
        egesszamosszeg := egesszamosszeg + egesszamosszeg(n - 1);
end;

begin
    writeln(egesszamosszeg(10)); 
end.
```

Answer (score 0):

You are simply *trying to increment* `egesszamosszeg` (*couldn't you use an easier name*?), instead of adding the consecutive numbers to it. But your loop is wrong: `eggesszamosszeg` is 0, so you are in fact doing `for n := 1 to 0 do`. That loop will never run. Don't re-use `n`, use another variable for the loop index:

```
for i := 1 to n do 
  egesszamosszeg := egesszamosszeg + i;
```

But you say it must be recursive, so it must call itself with a different parameter value. Then do something like:

```
function egesszamosszeg(n: integer): integer;
begin
  if n = 1 then // terminating condition
    egesszamosszeg := 1  
  else
    egesszamosszeg := n + egesszamosszeg(n - 1); // recursion
end;
```

*In most Pascals, you can use the pseudo-variable `Result` instead of the function name. Often, that makes typing a little easier.*

---

FWIW, did you know that you could make this a little simpler and do not need recursion or iteration at all? The result can be calculated directly:

```
function egesszamosszeg(n: Integer): Integer;
begin
  result := n * (n + 1) div 2;
end;
```

For 1..10, that will give `10 * 11 div 2 = 55` too.

See: https://www.wikihow.com/Sum-the-Integers-from-1-to-N

In effect, you count `(1+10) + (2+9) + (3+8) + (4+7) + (5+6) = 5 * 11 = 55`. You can do the same for any positive number. Same with 1..6: `(1+6) + (2+5) + (3+4) = 3 * 7 = 21`.
That leads to the formula:

```
sum = n * (n + 1) div 2
```

(or actually:

```
n div 2 * (n+1) // mathematically: n/2 * (n+1)
```

which is the same).

Comment: I would disagree with "You are simply incrementing egesszamosszeg" as the loop never runs as designed.  Small point but at the heart of the code's design issues.

Comment: @cdlane: you are right. It looked like a valid loop, at first, but that would never work. See my edits.